# How to use helper in laravel for confiig files?

Tags: laravel

After install `composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable` package. I have created a custom helper.

**composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],"files": [
        "app/Helpers/Helper.php"
    ]
},
```

After it, I ran in terminal `composer dump-autoload.

**app/Helpers/Helper.php**

```
<?php

class Helper {
    function slug($string, $separator = '-') {
        $_transliteration = ["/ö|œ/" => "e",
            "/ü/" => "e",
            "/Ä/" => "e",
            "/Ü/" => "e",
            "/Ö/" => "e",
            "/À|Á|Â|Ã|Å|Ǻ|Ā|Ă|Ą|Ǎ/" => "",
            "/à|á|â|ã|å|ǻ|ā|ă|ą|ǎ|ª/" => "",
            "/Ç|Ć|Ĉ|Ċ|Č/" => "",
            "/ç|ć|ĉ|ċ|č/" => "",
            "/Ð|Ď|Đ/" => "",
            "/ð|ď|đ/" => "",
            "/È|É|Ê|Ë|Ē|Ĕ|Ė|Ę|Ě/" => "",
            "/è|é|ê|ë|ē|ĕ|ė|ę|ě/" => "",
            "/Ĝ|Ğ|Ġ|Ģ/" => "",
            "/ĝ|ğ|ġ|ģ/" => "",
            "/Ĥ|Ħ/" => "",
            "/ĥ|ħ/" => "",
            "/Ì|Í|Î|Ï|Ĩ|Ī| Ĭ|Ǐ|Į|İ/" => "",
            "/ì|í|î|ï|ĩ|ī|ĭ|ǐ|į|ı/" => "",
            "/Ĵ/" => "",
            "/ĵ/" => "",
            "/Ķ/" => "",
            "/ķ/" => "",
            "/Ĺ|Ļ|Ľ|Ŀ|Ł/" => "",
            "/ĺ|ļ|ľ|ŀ|ł/" => "",
            "/Ñ|Ń|Ņ|Ň/" => "",
            "/ñ|ń|ņ|ň|ŉ/" => "",
            "/Ò|Ó|Ô|Õ|Ō|Ŏ|Ǒ|Ő|Ơ|Ø|Ǿ/" => "",
            "/ò|ó|ô|õ|ō|ŏ|ǒ|ő|ơ|ø|ǿ|º/" => "",
            "/Ŕ|Ŗ|Ř/" => "",
            "/ŕ|ŗ|ř/" => "",
            "/Ś|Ŝ|Ş|Ș|Š/" => "",
            "/ś|ŝ|ş|ș|š|ſ/" => "",
            "/Ţ|Ț|Ť|Ŧ/" => "",
            "/ţ|ț|ť|ŧ/" => "",
            "/Ù|Ú|Û|Ũ|Ū|Ŭ|Ů|Ű|Ų|Ư|Ǔ|Ǖ|Ǘ|Ǚ|Ǜ/" => "",
            "/ù|ú|û|ũ|ū|ŭ|ů|ű|ų|ư|ǔ|ǖ|ǘ|ǚ|ǜ/" => "",
            "/Ý|Ÿ|Ŷ/" => "",
            "/ý|ÿ|ŷ/" => "",
            "/Ŵ/" => "",
            "/ŵ/" => "",
            "/Ź|Ż|Ž/" => "",
            "/ź|ż|ž/" => "",
            "/Æ|Ǽ/" => "E",
            "/ß/" => "s",
            "/Ĳ/" => "J",
            "/ĳ/" => "j",
            "/Œ/" => "E",
            "/ƒ/" => ""];
        $quotedReplacement = preg_quote($separator, '/');
        $merge = [
            '/[^\s\p{Zs}\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lo}\p{Lt}\p{Lu}\p{Nd}]/mu' => ' ',
            '/[\s\p{Zs}]+/mu' => $separator,
            sprintf('/^[%s]+|[%s]+$/', $quotedReplacement, $quotedReplacement) => '',
        ];
        $map = $_transliteration + $merge;
        unset($_transliteration);
        return preg_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $string);
    }
}
```

**config/sluggable.php**

```
'method' => Helper::slug,
```

I tried deleting everything inside the vendor and do composer install and composer update still no luck.

I did try a command like dump-autoload, optimize, clear-compiled, etc. too.

Thanks.

Comment: take a look here bro https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7671

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make helper in laravel you can follow , two way , first :-
in composer.json like this :-

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/Helper.php"
    ]
},
then you should run this command composer dump-autoload
```

second way :-
create app service provider then register it then add this code inside your register method :-

```
public function register()
{
    foreach (glob(app_path().'/Helpers/*.php') as $filename){
        require_once($filename);
    }
}
```

but in your case try to make your method like this to be sure the helper file registered :-

```
if (! function_exists('slug')) {
    function slug($string, $separator = '-') {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not understand what you meant `but in your case try to make your method like this to be sure the helper file registered:-`

Comment: Do you mean this?      https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQgHS.png

Comment: When I add new content. The `slug` save like `sth` . https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYThz.png

Comment: And, In the `config/sluggable.php` file I have a command called `'method' => Helper::slug,`, What should I do?

Comment: in my case , i just explain how to register helper files , with 2 way . from your question , i mean you have problem in register helper in your laravel app . if you still face problem explain to us .